# Oracle: Create function based index

Tags: oracle

I am getting missing right parenthesis error when creating below function index.

```
create index user_emp_status on users(emp_status <> 'Terminated');
```

Basically I have a large number of users in this table and I would always be querying for users whose employment status is not terminated. I need to retain terminated employees in the table but looking to improve query performance using this index.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I figured out

```
create index user_emp_status on users(case emp_status when 'Active' then 'Active' end);
```

this way index is storing only active users.